# How can I dump data that I want of some SQLite3 tables in SQL format?

Tags: sql, sqlite, dump

I know how to select which table I want to dump in SQL format with the shell command:
$ ./sqlite3 test.db '.dump mytable' > test.sql
But this command selects all the data of "mytable"

Can I select the data in my table that I want before dump and how?
In other terms I seek a command like :
$ ./sqlite3 test.db '.dump select name from mytable' > test.sql
Obviously this command does not work :'(

Comment: Can't you create a view, and dump that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do it within the sqlite console is to create a temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp AS SELECT (field1, field2 ... ) FROM yourTable WHERE ... ;
.dump tmp
DROP TABLE tmp
```

Comment: I feared that ^^
IS there a way to recover the fields of a table to create the tempory table ?

Comment: I find this magic command => CREATE TABLE tmp AS SELECT * FROM yourTable ;
Thanks for your help
See you

Comment: Good to know. Edited my answer for others using this command. Cheers.